# JavaFX: Binding not working unexpectedly

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have a binding that does not work, but yet I have no way to replicate this at all.

Before I explain what exactly didn't work correctly, this is the nearest sample code that I can come up with, that **does not** actually produce the problem:

```
public class Foo extends Application {

    private final Bar bar = new Bar();

    private final BooleanProperty test = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);

        root.setPrefSize(800, 800);

        Pane hoverPane = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(hoverPane);
        hoverPane.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        hoverPane.setLayoutX(300);
        hoverPane.setLayoutY(300);

        bar.hoveredProperty().bind(hoverPane.hoveredProperty());
        bar.hoveredProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
            // This one doesn't work correctly
            System.out.println("Bar received change");
        });

        // If this commented block is used instead of the normal binding, 
        // then "Bar received change" would be printed correctly.
        /*
         * hoverPane.addListener((a, b, c) -> {
         *     bar.hoveredProperty().set(c);
         * });
         */

        hoverPane.hoveredProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
            // This line appears appear whenever I shift my mouse in and out
            System.out.println("HoverPane's hover property has changed");
        });

        test.bind(hoverPane.hoveredProperty());

        test.addListener((a,b,c) -> {
            // I get one line of this every time I hover in and out too
            System.out.println("Test property received change");
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class Bar {

    private final BooleanProperty hovered = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public final BooleanProperty hoveredProperty() { return hovered; }
    public final boolean getHovered() { return this.hovered.get(); }
    public final void setHovered(boolean h) { this.hovered.set(h); }
}
```

The actual codes are a lot more complex than this (in several thousand lines). There are a lot of containers (`Pane` objects) placed on the `Scene`, so it's not just one `hoverPane`.

The problem is, some of these `Pane` objects *do* receive the hover value changes, while some *do not*. I would say all the `Pane` objects are the same, because they are instances of the same custom `Pane` class that I wrote.

Just like what my sample code says, I am very sure that these panes' `hoveredProperty()` are definitely changing whenever I mouse in and out of them, which means that there is nothing there that has messed up my mouse events.

When I use the binding, some panes would receive the change in corresponding `Bar` object, while some do not. Those that do receive, would always receive the change, no matter how many times I re-run the application. On the other hand, those that do not receive, will never ever receive the change.

When I switch from binding to `ChangeListener`, all panes would receive the change. This is the first thing that baffles me.

Furthermore, I added an extra test boolean property, which is also bound similarly to `Bar.hoveredProperty()`, the result is that all these test bindings worked correctly. This one is the one that totally confuses me.

I understand this is not going to be easy for anyone to help considering I don't have a working MCV sample that demonstrates the problem. I am just hoping that there is someone out there who has met such weird problem.

Comment: See if http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html helps (particularly the "accidental garbage collection" section).

Comment: @James_D Thanks. I was already thinking about something similar when I'm looking at these symptoms. But when I looked at the source codes for `bind()`, it looks like the only weak reference is the reference of the bound property held by the internal `InvalidationListener`. Since I am sure I have strong reference of all my properties, then there should not be any problem. Actually, I already have the solution that makes this work, but the scariest part of this problem is that I have lost confidence in the binding system - I have no idea which of my binding would mysteriously stop working.